# Height of firefox bookmark toolbar

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to customize the firefox bookmarks toolbar by reducing the font and icon size to increase the space of the actual window. I've edited `userChrome.css` by adding

```css
* {
 font-size: 12px !important;
}

#PersonalToolbar {
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 10 !important; height: 15px !important; max-height: 15px !important;
}
```

The bookmark toolbar now looks like 
[image: this]

How can I shift the bookmarks up such that they're centered in the bar?

Comment: Negative top-margin?

Comment: did the job with some fiddling around. +1